# Excel VBA - Compare Sheet Name to Values in Named Range, Perform Formula if Not Found

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I had some help earlier to create this code -

```
Sub PopulateUptime()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Uptime" And ws.Name <> "26 Apr 16" Then
       With Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value2 = "'" & ws.Name
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/168)"
        .Offset(, 2).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/(168 - ('" & ws.Name & "'!FN40/60)))"
       End With
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

This take each worksheet and copies the name into "Uptime" worksheet along with a couple of formulas to generate a table with Col.A (Value = ws.Name) being a date.

I'm now trying to create a new macro to account for when new sheets are added.  I want the macro to recognise when a sheet is new and add it to the end of the table.  My thinking currently has been that I can loop through each sheet again and attempt to match it to values in "Uptime"!Col.A which I have named "Commencing".  I'm not sure if this is the best technique, but this is the code I have -

```
Sub UpdateUptime()


Dim ws As Worksheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Uptime" Then
       With Worksheets("Uptime")
            For Each MyCell In Sheets("Uptime").Range("Commencing")
                If MyCell.Value <> ws.Name Then
                   With Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        .Value2 = "'" & ws.Name
                        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/168)"
                        .Offset(, 2).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/(168 - ('" & ws.Name & "'!FN40/60)))"
                   End With
                End If
            Next MyCell
        End With
    End If
Next ws


End Sub
```

For some reason it's not working. I knew it would be slow to do it this way, but it just runs endlessly. When I hit 'Esc' to stop the macro it turns out that it's been copying multiple rows for sheets that ARE already in the table.  I must have gone wrong with the looping or the naming somehow, but I'm not sure where.

I also tried the below code to see if it was possible to do it without looping through the namedRange, but this gives me a Error 13 Type Mismatch on the second If.

```
Sub UpdateUptime()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Uptime" Then
       If ws.Name <> Sheets("Uptime").Range("Commencing").Value2 Then
          With Worksheets("Uptime").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
               .Value2 = "'" & ws.Name
               .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/168)"
               .Offset(, 2).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/(168 - ('" & ws.Name & "'!FN40/60)))"
          End With
       End If
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

**My VBA skills are clearly not sufficient here.  Could anybody help?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub UpdateUptime()

    Dim ws                    As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Uptime" Then
            With Worksheets("Uptime")
                If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, .Range("Commencing"), 0)) Then
                    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        .Value2 = "'" & ws.Name
                        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/168)"
                        .Offset(, 2).Formula = "=(('" & ws.Name & "'!ET40/60)/(168 - ('" & ws.Name & "'!FN40/60)))"
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next ws


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again Rory.  Thanks for leaping to the rescue once again.  Unfortunately this doesn't quite work.  Instead of adding on any unmatched worksheet names it adds all of them onto the bottom again.

Is it possible to modify the Match function?

Comment: Can you try the edited code above please? If that doesn't work, can you put a sample workbook somewhere?

Comment: You've done it!  Just had to remove that apostrophe?  Excel is melting my brain, but I've learned a lot more just through this process.  Just got to add some charting functionality, which should be fairly simple and I can wrap this up.

Thank you so much for your help Rory.

With a bit of luck I'll get some server hosting soon and I can start learning in a C#/SQL/PHP environment!